# Querying PartitionKey and RowKey syntax in Azure Table Storage service

Tags: azure, rest, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Meanwhile reading [querying tables and entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities) in **Azure Table Storage service** on Microsoft docs I found `PartitionKey` and `RowKeys` can be filtered in 2 different ways in the *myaccount.table.core.windows.net* URL as the following:

```
https://<service-url>/Customers(PartitionKey='MyPartition',RowKey='MyRowKey1')
```

And using `$filter` to achieve the same:

```
https://<service-url>/Customers()?$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'MyPartitionKey'%20and%20RowKey%20eq%20'MyRowKey1'
```

I understand from the documentation `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` properties are forming the entity's primary key so the first syntax can be used as well as the [Filtering on the PartitionKey and RowKey Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#filtering-on-the-partitionkey-and-rowkey-properties) part states:

> Because the PartitionKey and RowKey properties form an entity's primary key, you can use a special syntax to identify the entity.

***Questions:***

1. Is there any drawbacks, disadvantages using `$filter` instead of that special syntax what has been mentioned?
2. Does it matter which one I use in my solution?

Any clarification is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you using any SDK to fetch the entities or directly calling the REST API?

Comment: @GauravMantri Directly the REST API I assume, currently just reading the documentation. This is a theoretical question. I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesing question! So I tried to perform both the operations to fetch an entity using Postman and the time it took to get the data was almost identical (between 250ms - 300ms).

So as long as you're using REST API, I don't think it would matter.

When you use the SDK (WindowsAzure.Storage version 9.3.3 for example), there're different methods that uses these features. Take a look at the sample code below:

```
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TableName");

        //This uses https://account.table.core.windows.net/table(PartitionKey='pk', RowKey='rk')
        TableOperation op = TableOperation.Retrieve("pk", "rk");
        var entity = table.Execute(op).Result as DynamicTableEntity;

        //This uses https://account.table.core.windows.net/table?$filter=PartitionKey eq 'pk' and RowKey eq 'rk'
        TableQuery query = new TableQuery();
        query.FilterString = "PartitionKey eq 'pk' and RowKey eq 'rk'";
        var entity = table.ExecuteQuery(query).FirstOrDefault();
```